# Problem with anchor links (T3 Framework)

Tags: menu, menu-item, t3-framework

I am using this javascript for smooth scroll to the desired item on the main page.

https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll

I can not solve 2 problems:

1. Two menu (Menu Item Type: External URL) contains external anchor links and look like this: #about_us.
   Added to the scrollable element anchors .
   When i click on a menu item script works and moves in the right place, but because of internal links (for example from another menu item with article) does not go back.
2. It is impossible to calibrate scrolling. It turns or less than you need to scroll or higher.
   Please help me )

Comment: Can you provide more information to question.  T3 framework V3 I assume you're using.  Are you building your own template or using a Joomlart one? Details of issues logged in Browser console and example of the script you are posting to call smooth_scroll.